# How to disable latex in doxygen config

Tags: latex, doxygen

I want doxygen documentation generator not to generate any LaTeX files at all. HTML is enough for me. Is it possible to configure doxygen.ini to do so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If with `doxygen.ini` you mean doxygen's configuration file, then you can set `GENERATE_LATEX` to `NO` in order to disable the LaTeX output.